# Is there a shared pool of memory for files in iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there a shared pool of memory or a shared directory in iOS where applications can read and write files?

Comment: You can communication with standard applications like Photos, Calendar, Contacts. Apple provide several frameworks/functions for this aims.

Comment: if it so then can we add a file like a text/pdf file into photos

Comment: I don't know all the details about different files, but for writing image into Photos you need to use function - `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(UIImage *image, ...` and pass to it onlyy UIImage

Comment: Yes, there is! But only if you run your iOS apps in the iPhone simulator! (Sorry for being snarky, but this "feature" of the iPhone simulator made me believe that the "shared directory" available to OS X programs was also available to iOS apps. It worked fine until I started testing my app on a real device ...)

Comment: @RenniePet thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, each application is sandboxed. Applications can only read and write files/data within their own sandbox.

From the [File System Programming Guide: File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2):

> Every Application Is an Island - An iOS application’s interactions with
>   the file system are limited mostly to the directories inside the
>   application’s sandbox. During installation of a new application, the
>   installer code creates a home directory for the application, places
>   the application in that directory, and creates several other key
>   directories. These directories constitute the application’s primary
>   view of the file system. Figure 1-1 shows a representation of the
>   sandbox for an application.

If you need to open files of a particular type in your application, you can register your application with the system letting it know what types of files you support. Files are shared with your application through an API, not a globally shared directory. Take a look at the [Document Interaction Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1) for more information on how to do that.

Comment: then how can a gmail app or someother does save images to photos


similar to that

Comment: Have a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html The document interaction framework is the "glue" between apps that allow apps to send files to another app.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> For security reasons, iOS places each app (including its preferences
>   and data) in a sandbox at install time. A sandbox is a set of
>   fine-grained controls that limit the app’s access to files,
>   preferences, network resources, hardware, and so on. As part of the
>   sandboxing process, the system installs each app in its own sandbox
>   directory, which acts as the home for the app and its data.

You cannot access anything outside the sandbox in non-jailbroken iOS devices.

EDIT:

There are special classes designed to access things like pictures, music, contacts etc. For pictures you can have a look at [UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) and [Camera Programming Topics for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010400). For music you can look at the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765). And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the info. but how does photos are shared to other apps. they can save to photos. upload potos? is this a shared one. if so can i downlaod a file and save it to photos section

Comment: Edited answer following your comment.